# How to bring variable values from csv to rivescript?

Tags: python, csv, rivescript

In rivescript, if a user asks me the price of a certain item, I want the bot to look for that items' price in the csv file. Im new to to rivescript so any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use macro for doing this.

`> object read_from_csv python
   #code to read from CSV
    return ""
< object`

**From rive response**

`-<call>read_from_csv <star></call>`